# Check box doesnt seem to checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby and below is the problem i am facing. In my index.html i have this piece  of code for check box

```
= form_tag movies_path, :id=>"ratings_form", :method => :get do
  Include: 
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", :id => "ratings_#{rating}"
    = submit_tag 'Refresh', :id => "ratings_submit"
```

while in my controller i have

```
def index
#@movies = Movie.all
@sort = params[:sort]
@movies = Movie.order(@sort)
@all_ratings = Movie.all_ratings
debugger
end
```

and at the debug point i am expecting the values of those check boxes that are checked but there is just nil

```
(rdb:53) puts params[:ratings]

nil
```

Entire param

```
(rdb:53) puts params

{"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"movies"}  

nil
```

Comment: print the entire `params`. Maybe you're just looking with the wrong key.

Comment: doesnt help, please see the edited question

Comment: Well, seems like the form doesn't get sent.

Comment: Since it is a get request, you should be able to see the params in your URL. What does the URL look like after submitting the form?